# Create user after node created and assign node entity reference to it

Tags: users, entities

I have a content type with name `hotel` it have `entity reference` field that referenced to `users` entity, I want when admin create a node automatically created a user according to `hotel email field` and then set  `user entity reference` field with that new created user.How can I do it automatically?

I create a rule with below structure but **not work**

```
{ "rules_create_user_based_on_hotel" : {
    "LABEL" : "create user based on hotel",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "node_insert--hotel" : { "bundle" : "hotel" } },
    "DO" : [
      { "entity_create" : {
          "USING" : {
            "type" : "user",
            "param_name" : "[node:field_hotel_users]",
            "param_mail" : "[node:field_mail_hotel]"
          },
          "PROVIDE" : { "entity_created" : { "entity_created" : "Created entity" } }
        }
      },
      { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "node:field-user-ref" ], "value" : [ "entity-created" ] } }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: your mistake is in `"data_set" : { "data" : [ "node:field-user-ref" ], "value" : [ "entity-created" ]` ,  use `[ "entity-created:uid" ]` instead of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also handle it programmatically in your custom module.

```
function yourmodule_form_alter(&$form,$form_state,$form_id){
     global $user;

     if($form_id=='hotel_node_form'  && !isset($form['nid']['#value'])){
         $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = '_hotel_user_register_submit';
     }
}

function _hotel_user_register_submit($form,$form_state){
    $uname=$form_state['values']['field_hotel_users']['und'][0]['value'];
    $uemail=$form_state['values']['field_mail_hotel']['und'][0]['email'];

    $new_user = array(
     'name' => $uname,
     'pass' => rand(1000000,9999999), // note: do not md5 the password
     'mail' => $uemail,
     'status' => 1,
     'init' => $uemail,
     'roles' => array(
        DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID => 'authenticated user',
    ),
);
    $nuser=user_save('', $new_user);
    $node=node_load($form_state['values']['nid']);
    $node->field_user_ref['und'][0]['target_id']=$nuser->uid;
    node_submit($node);
    node_save($node);
}
```

Comment: Please, don't copy what already said in another answer; it is still visible, even if it is not the accepted one.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I tried to create comprehensive answer, I think doing this job with rules is better method but when he had problem with doing it ( or maybe because his settings and configuration) I try to suggest another method that I believe is not better solution, So try create comprehensive answer .

Comment: @zhilevan no need to " create comprehensive answer". On the contrary, keeping solutions in separate answers helps people to vote for them separately, allowing future users to see community's opinion (good thing) and rewarding one who actually wrote particular solution first (really, really good thing).

Comment: @Mołot ok my friend, tnx for your notice.

Answer (score 4):

- Download the [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module
- Enable Rules and **Rules UI**

Add a new rule

- **React on event**: After Saving New Content (it's listed under NODE)
- **Restrict by type**: Hotel

Under Action

- Add Action of **Create New Entity** >> ENTITY TYPE: **USER** >> For your EMAIL field, Ex: **If you called your field "Email"** then it's **node:field-email**. `For user name, I guess you will also need to create a field in the node for that too. Then do same steps as e-mail`

Note: You can always click on "DATA SELECTORS" to see all the tokens you can use.

- Add Action of **Set data value** >> select your entity ref field (Ex: **If you called your field "Test"** then it's **node:field-test)** >> for Value use **entity-created:uid**
- Add action of **Send Account Email** (`listed under USER`) >> Account: **entity-created**

> You can modify the e-mail templates here
>   `/admin/config/people/accounts` use tokens for your needs.
>
> Let me know how this goes, no time to test this Rule.